# How to output dictionary to dataframe including None type values

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is loaded from JSON that looks as such:

`{'Exist': False, 'IDs': []}`

I want to produce this to a dataframe. Using the following:

`df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)`

Results in:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Exist, IDs]
Index: []
```

However, I would like to achieve the following:

```
Exist    IDs
False    None/nan/whatever/(empty)
```

If the list is empty, or it is a None type, I want it left blank or some indication that it is non..

This will eventually be written to an Excel report.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this since you are saving it in excel

```
pd.DataFrame(list({'Exist': False, 'IDs': []}.items())).T.to_excel('file.xlsx', header = False, index = False)
```

Comment: Any chance I can change orientation?

Comment: pd.DataFrame(list({'Exist': False, 'IDs': []}.items())).T to do transpose

Comment: Thank you so much!